# Google sign-in inside Node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I want to integrate google sign-in in my Node.js script so I can log who used that script.
I am able to add google sign-in in webpage with help of https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in but could not find way to add google sign-in in standlaone script.

Let me try explain my intention

```
var googleSignIn = async function () {
    // sign in using google account and return email addess on succesfull sign in
}

var work = async function () {
    // step 1: log in first using google
    var email = await googleSignIn()

    // step 2: talk to backed server api on succesfull login
    if (email) {
        console.log('calling backend api')
    } else {
        console.log('you need to login first')
    }
}

work().then(function () {
    console.log('done')
}).catch(function (error) {
    throw error
})
```

I want to implement `googleSignIn` method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your script would need to operate in the same manner as a desktop app, and perform these actions:

- Create an authorization redirect URL in terms of Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Open the system browser, which will manage redirects and the user login
- Receive the response in your app, via either a Loopback or Private URI Scheme notification
- The response contains an authorization code, which needs to be swapped for tokens
- You can then call your API with an access token

A typical URL would be a value like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=y792f434f
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=com.mycompany.myapp:/callback
&scope=...
&state=...
&code_challenge=...
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

It is a tricky flow to implement though - in case useful there are further details in my [Desktop OAuth Blog Posts](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/17/desktop-app-how-to-run-the-code-sample/), and code samples you can run ...

Comment: There should be clean approch for this as its a common requirement.